# Make Sinatra Helpers Available in Modules everywhere?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

How can I make my Sinatra helpers available everywhere?

Sometimes I can't access them (e.g. from modules, see below). I'd like them to be tied to the 'global namespace' s.t. they can be invoked by their name, from anywhere.

Below is a working Sinatra app demonstrating the problem.

```
require 'sinatra'

helpers do
  def bar
    "bar"
  end
end

get '/helper' do
  bar #works 
end

get '/module_and_helper' do 
  Foo.foo #crashes. How can I fix this?
end

module Foo
  extend self

  def foo
    bar
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: From my understanding `helpers` are defined at the top level of the application making it accessible to all objects and methods contained inside the application object. The problem here is that your module is defined at a higher level outside of the application itself. to resolve this I would suggest including it in the application e.g. `class Sinatra::Application; include Foo;end` either that or define a module (e.g. `MyModule`) at true top level  and then call `helpers MyModule`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. My actual application is larger than the included example, of course; I'm running it by 'requiring' all of my files (which include the routes, the helpers, and the modules) and then calling 

run Sinatra::Application

Where in such a configuration do/can I make the helpers available to a module?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @engineersmnky. Instead of using 'helpers do' you can define a separate Module and `include` it in the app, apparently rendering it available everywhere.

```
require 'sinatra'

module Helpers
  extend self

  def barrio
    "barrio"
  end
end

include Helpers

get '/helper' do
  barrio #works
end

get '/module_and_helper' do 
  Foo.foo #works!
end

module Foo
  extend self

  def foo
    barrio
  end
end
```